# Converting html em tag to react Text component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a text string with a bunch of `<em>` blocks that I would like to convert to  components but have had no luck with doing this. Any pointers for anyone whos done something similar?

data.snippet is an array of strings, some of which contain `<em>` tags

```
const convertEMToText = ({data}) => {
    console.log(data.snippet[1])
    for(var i=0; i<data.snippet.length; i++) {
      returnSnippetText(data.snippet[i], data.snippet[i].includes("<em>"));
    }
  }

  const returnSnippetText = ({text, isH}) => {
    if(isH) {
      return (
        <Text style={styles.highlighted}>{text}</Text>
      );
    }
    else {
      return (
        <Text>{text}</Text>
      );
    }
  }
```

I call convertEMToText and nothing happens.

Comment: Please give more information. Can you give some sample code?

Comment: @NanoBit I have added my non-working code and more explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

returnSnippetText function is expecting one object parameter with text and ish properties. but you pass two parameters.

use

```
... returnSnippetText({text:data.snippet[i], isH:data.snippet[i].includes("<em>")});
```

or

```
const returnSnippetText = (text, isH) => { ...
```

*remove the { } of ({text, isH})

about comment of nothing printed out you can:

```
const convertEMToText = ({data}) => {
    console.log(data.snippet[1])
    let response = [ ];
    for(var i=0; i<data.snippet.length; i++) {
      response.push( rereturnSnippetText(data.snippet[i], data.snippet[i].includes("<em>")) );
    }
  return response;
  }
```

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you're suggesting here.

Comment: when you use function({param1, param2, param3, etc}) actually is a function with 1 argument.

Comment: I tried this and still nothing. Nothing is being printed out. It seems that the problems is because `convertEMToText` doesnt `return` the results from `returnSnippetText` but if I return from inside the for loop of `returnSnippetText` only 1 line will print. How can I get it to return each line in the loop?